# including external js files in laravel 5.1.2

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

I'm working with laravel for the first time, i'm currently running the 5.1.2 version, i'm having issues with including external js files from the /public/js/ directory into the master view file using the asset() function. it works with css files though. i have this in my master file:

```
    <!-- load angularJS lib -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/angular/angular.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- load angularJS loader lib -->
<script src="{{asset('js/angular/angular-loader.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/metro.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/app.style.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/Jquery/jquery-2.1.4.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Page renders HTML source code as such:

```
<!-- load angularJS lib -->
<script src="http://localhost/Online-Phone/public/js/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- load angularJS loader lib -->
<script src="http://localhost/Online-Phone/public/js/angular/angular-loader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/Online-Phone/public/js/metro.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/Online-Phone/public/js/app.style.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/Online-Phone/public/js/Jquery/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What does it render in the html source code?

Comment: renders the above peice of code.

Comment: Ok. In the html source code, if you click in the location of the js file, does it load the file correctly? If yes, please move the jquery line to the top of the pile.

Comment: Please show an example of how you include css files.

Answer (score 1):

Including files located in "public/" folder.

1) "URL::asset()" works only with ".blade.php" file.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/jquery-ui.css') }}">`

2) Plain file

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
{{HTML::style('css/style.css')}}
```

`{{ HTML::script('js/javascript.js') }}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It works

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('js/angular/angular.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: `URL::asset()` and `asset()` are the syntactically equal in Laravel 5.1, so if one doesn't work, the other one won't.